# Implementing your own LINQ & IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, performance, ienumerable

In a project I am working on, there are really huge collections (1M-1B elements), and things are modified as collections mostly.

It's a real-time app, and so the performance is paramount.

For some of the operations, like Reverse, BinarySearch (possible?), etc will suffer more than others like Select, etc.

Is it feasible to implement one's own IEnumerable with possible MoveNext, MovePrev, etc and own implemented LINQ extensions that take advantages of these?

If this is gonna happen, it's gonna happen at the end of the project. Because we need to get it working first, then make it faster.

All in all this shouldn't be too much work, right?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear how you plan to realize a performance gain by rolling your own interface for sequences.  What's the plan, here, exactly?  What code are you worried about and trying to replace?

Comment: I'd add that if you're numbering the elements of your collection in the millions, you probably aren't storing that all in memory at once, right?  So a naive approach to retrieval is going to be what costs you, by way of disk or network access costs or whatever.  If you're worried about performance, you are going to have to come up with more complicated abstractions than just simple enumerations, anyway.

Comment: It's really broad to include all details here, but as a simple example, the Reverse functionality for instance, or BinarySearch ing a collection for WhereSorted or something.

Comment: For your 2nd comment, do you have any idea which approach would be better? They are gonna be modified often enough if not very often. Should they be on disk?

Comment: Well, I don't quite see why you expect your binary search to be faster than the .NET array binary search, or your list-reverse-thing to be faster, etc.  They have pretty smart people around to write a good binary search.  If you have your own complicated collection and you want to do a binary search, then yeah, I guess you'll write your own -- what's the alternative?

Comment: Re: disk caching -- nobody can really answer that without a careful analysis of the different ways your data is being retrieved and modified.

Comment: The alternative is to stick with what we have in .NET. Btw when I said BinarySearch I meant to use it in LINQ queries, so chaining the calls and get correct results. Not use it after the collection is created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's very definitely possible to create your own implementation of `Enumerable` which might special-case some situations. You'd basically want to detect your own collection types (or possibly just collections such as `List<T>`) and use a more efficient implementation where applicable.

I have a [sample project](http://csharpindepth.com/Files/LinqIn60Minutes.zip) which I used to demo "implementing LINQ to Objects in an hour" which you might like to look at for examples. It's not a full implementation and in particular it's *less* efficient than the real LINQ to Objects - but you may still find it interesting.

Alternatively, you may find that [i4o (Indexed LINQ)](http://www.codeplex.com/i4o) does everything you need out of the box - or that you would be better off contributing to that than starting from scratch. Worth checking out.

Just remember that at the end of the day, LINQ is basically a nice design coupled with syntactic sugar. The C# compiler doesn't know *anything* special about `System.Linq.Enumerable`, for example.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I will check out both projects. You said "C# compiler doesn't know anything special...", but I will lose the query syntax, right? Or will the compiler use mine if the names are matching, like Select and Where?

Comment: The latter. The C# compiler knows about the *pattern* but not the specifics. You could implement the query pattern over a *totally* different type if you wanted to. See chapters 11 and 12 of C# in Depth for more details, if you've got it.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I sure have it. Didn't start yet, but will take a look at those chapters.

Comment: where would you prefer people buy C# in Depth from?

Comment: @smartcaveman: In general, http://manning.com/skeet2 - but if you're outside the US, your local Amazon may be cheaper.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want performance, you can do quite a lot. Remember that the following selection:

```
var result = from element in collection
             where element.Id == id
             select element;
```

Compiles as:

```
var result = collection.Where(element => element.Id == id);
```

If you create the following method for the type of `collection`, then you can exploit the fact that the primary action is equality of the Id member and handle the request in an optimized manner. The important thing is correctly identifying the performance-critical operations on your collection and choosing the correct algorithms (i.e. complexity) to perform them.

```
public IEnumerable<TElement> Where(Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> selector)
{
    // detect equality of the Id member and return some special value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse() - this method fully enumerates the IEnumerable before returning the first result.

If your query is myCollection.Reverse().Take(10), and your collection has Billions of items, it is a horrible idea to enumerate the billions of items to get 10 out.

If you supplied a Reverse method on your own type, you could supply a better implementation that simply loops backwards over the collection (by index possibly).

The key to this is supplying your own type where you control the implementations.  You can't use the implementations that work for all `IEnumerable<T>` because those implementations won't take full advantage of the capabilities of your custom collection type.

Comment: Thanks David, that's a good example I was thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it feasible to implement one's own
>   IEnumerable with possible MoveNext,
>   MovePrev, etc and own implemented LINQ
>   extensions that take advantages of
>   these?

`IEnumerable` (or more properly, `IEnumerator`) doesn't have `MovePrev`. You could define an interface:

```
public interface IReversable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    IEnumerator<T> GetReverseEnumerator();
}
```

This could be implemented by any container that supports efficient reverse enumeration.

You could then write an overload of `Reverse` (the extension method) to work off this new interface, and collection classes that implement the interface, etc. And then you'd have to use those collection classes instead of standard ones like `List<T>`.

But (I don't have Reflector handy to check) it may be that the built-in `Reverse` is smart enough to do things the quick way if it can get the `IList` interface from the collection, which would optimise the most common cases just fine anyway.

So there may not be a lot of point in this kind of approach.

Comment: Thanks Earwicker. This way the correct method would be called over my collection, right? i.e. it wouldn't call default Reverse on MyCollection.

Comment: Please note I'm saying there's probably NOT a lot of point doing this. And if you ever want to be sure that a specific method implementation will be called, you can always give it a new, different name. This has the added advantage that people reading your code will know your intentions, as well as the compiler. But yes, you could do this. But download Reflector and look at what Reverse does for `IList` before going to any manual effort - I don't know if it handles it differently, but it might.

Comment: I didn't see anything with IList in the Reverse iterator.